# Merging '<Files>' directives in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, file, mod-rewrite

My `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
<Files misc>
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>

<Files computers>
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>

<Files products>
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
```

...and several more. However, given that the directive is called File**s** (i.e. plural), it seems like there should be a way to condense these all down to one rule.

How would I do that? I tried a few things like commas and pipes but nothing has worked thus far, when I load the pages it displays all my PHP code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Files ~ "^(misc|computers|products)$">
    ForceType application/x-httpd-php
</Files>
```